# Introducing Data in a postgresql database from a php form & Validating the data in the form

Tags: php, database, postgresql, validation

I have a from to introduce the data and I'm trying to validate the data. However, either the data is introduced or not, the info is introduce in the database.

For example, If I leave the name blank, I get an error message that the name cannot be blank, but the blank name is introduce in the database.

How can I do, so only after all the fields have been validated, the data is introduce in the database?

Thank you so much

CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $surnameErr = "";
$name = $email = $surname = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
 $nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
 $emailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["surname"])) {
  $surname = "";
} else {
 $surname = test_input($_POST["surname"]);
}
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo        htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="surname">
<span class="error"><?php echo $surnameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $surname;
echo "<br>";
?>


<?php
   $db = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=postgres user=myusername password=mypassword');

    $firstname = pg_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $surname = pg_escape_string($_POST['website']);
    $emailaddress = pg_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO friends(firstname, surname, emailaddress)     VALUES('" . $firstname . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $emailaddress . "')";
    $result = pg_query($db, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        $errormessage = pg_last_error();
        echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
        exit();
    }
    printf ("These values were inserted into the database - %s %s %s", $firstname, $surname, $emailaddress);
    pg_close();
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because that's what you've got in your code. You check your POSTed values, print error messages and then run the query regardless of whether there were errors. Can you explain which step is confusing / unexpected?

Comment: I'm trying to change the code so the data is only introduce if all the validations have pass (so if all values have been introduce) but I don't know how to do that. My questions is: what do I need to do in my code, so data is only introduce in the database after all validations have been approved?  Kind of:                                                                                  If validations approved then      INSERT INTO database   else do nothing                                                                                                                       Thank you so much

Comment: Just something like `if ($nameErr == '' && $emailErr == '' ...)` around your database code. There's no magic involved here.